# Username in Wordpress 2.7 Admin not changing based on user

Tags: wordpress

Thanks in advance for any help, guys and gals!

I just upgraded to Wordpress 2.7, and have to admin accounts, but regardless of which one I log into, it still says "Howdy, Jesse..." in the top corner.

Anyone have any insight to this?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress will often display the Nickname, not the username. Are they the same for both accounts? If so, you are probably correctly logging in to both.

Comment: No, they are different for both accounts.
they are both logging in correctly (i set them to admins, and one can only delete the other when logged in, so i know im logging into seperate accounts).

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Each acct can be configured to display a variety of different names. The following pic shows the options for selection.

[visual name selection http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/0cf6c650b4.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/0cf6c650b4.gif)

You should be able to give each acct a different nick or a different selection if you want to tell them apart.